# Does 'p' have a special meaning in Django?

Tags: python, django

Why are p and p8 different in the following code?

The beginning of a view function (in file views.py in a Django app named "proteinSearch" with a model named "Protein" that has a field named "description"):

```
def searchForProteins2(request, searchStr):
    p8 = Protein.objects.filter( description__icontains=searchStr)

    #Why doesn't this work?????
    p  = Protein.objects.filter( description__icontains=searchStr)

    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Interactively in pdb:

```
    (Pdb) searchStr
    u'centr'
    (Pdb) p8
    [<Protein: IPI00657962.1>, <Protein: IPI00479143.2>, <Protein: IPI00477050.4>, <Protein: IPI00220625.1>,
    95.2>]
    (Pdb) p
    *** SyntaxError: SyntaxError('unexpected EOF while parsing', ('<string>', 0, 0, ''))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you are in Debugging mode (pdb or ipdb REPL), 'p' is meant for a specific functionality, i.e. evaluating an expression expr.

Like,

```
ipdb> x = 1
ipdb> p x
1
ipdb> p x==True
True
ipdb> p x==1
True
```

In Django, 'p' will simply means a variable.

If you want to print value of 'p' variable, try,

```
ipdb> p p
```

:)

Comment: I have followed the tutorial, http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/#intro-tutorial04. I now realise their choice of naming a variable 'p' is confusing because of the collision of a command in pdb: p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)

Comment: Exclamation point can also be used in front of the variable: !p

Comment: You can get a list of pdb commands by typing 'help' or you can take a look at the pdb docs: http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands

Comment: I'd like to add that this is one of the main reasons why you should never use single letter variable names... It usually just leads to confusion.

Comment: Very true. The only places where short variable names could be allowed to use in python, are list-comprehensions and lambda expr.